# Display list of assets that are in use?

Tags: assets, craft2

I am very new to Craft and how it works. I've got a client with a Craft site (v2.9.2), that I help them with. It was created by another developer.

I want to help them tidy up their Assets.

There are two folders (on S3) for their Assets. `/Media` and `/Media/Files`.

Scanning by eye, I can see `/Media/Files` *appears* to be a subset of what's in `Media` (meaning, they are duplicate files). Before we potentially delete the `/Media/Files` folder, I'd like to programatically confirm if any of them are being used. My suspicion is only files in `/Media/` are used on the site.

Is there any easy way to see which assets are in use, and where they are used?

I found questions on StackExchange re how to see what media is *not* in use, such as [this one](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22506/how-to-find-out-which-assets-are-being-used). I also found [a question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/how-do-i-display-a-list-of-assets-with-the-entries-they-are-related-to) on how to do something similar to what I need.

Although, to be honest, I had no idea where I'd utilise such code. I'm not going to get into creating a new plug-in.

For example, [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2010/10913) was shared in the answer to that question:

```
{% set content = craft.entries.section('content').find() %}
{% set usedFotos = craft.assets.relatedTo(content).order('filename').find() %}

{# Loop throught the array of assets #}
{% for usedFoto in usedFotos %}

    <h2>{{ usedFoto.filename }}</h2>
    <ul>

        {# Loop throught entries related to this asset #}
        {% for entry in craft.entries.relatedTo(usedFoto).order('title') %}
            <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}

    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

Where would I utilise this code?

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin that you can use to find unused assets: [Asset Usage](https://github.com/born05/craft-assetusage/tree/craft-2)

This gives you an extra column in the Assets listing to indicate if an asset is used or not. Unfortunately, the Craft 2 version doesn't have the console command to delete all unused assets that the Craft 3 version does, but this may help you anyway.